# Matching two columns with common values and fetching similar values

Tags: sql-server, outer-join

Probably a very basic question. I have two tables(SQL Server 2012) **Events** and **User Details**. First table is having a column which has user logins say 'xyz'. Second one has a column having user logins 'xyz', 'xyz-a', 'xyz-b' etc all with same User IDs.

If the user logins with suffix are present/absent in the second table, some flags have to be set accordingly. How can it be fetched?

Much appreciate any help. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: How can what be fetched?  Maybe `SELECT * FROM [User Details] WHERE column_name LIKE 'xyz-%'

Comment: How can what be fetched?  Maybe `SELECT * FROM [User Details] WHERE column_name LIKE 'xyz-%'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use like in join condition and [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)

```
    SELECT * FROM Events a INNER JOIN User_Details B ON a.userlogins  LIKE CONCAT( B.username, '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the "-" is always the delimiter in the second table you can do below.  The case statement first looks at if the "-" is present in the string, it looks only to the left of the dash, if the dash does not exist then it look at the entire login.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    EventsTable E
    JOIN UserDetailsTable U
        ON  E.LoginID = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',U.LoginID) > 0 THEN LEFT(U.LoginID,CHARINDEX('-',U.LoginID)-1) ELSE U.LoginID END
```